# How to assign width to flexbox items in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

```
.service-acc {
    display: flex; 
    gap: 10px; 
    width: 100%; 
    &-activity {
        width: 70%;
    }
    &-password {
        width: 30%;
    }
}
```

In the above SCSS code I am trying to assign the width for flex items by dividing them 70% and 30%, because I want the first item is bigger than the second.

The above SCSS works fine but I want to know whether this approach is correct or some other solution(or CSS properties) to do better than this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a great solution. How are you going to do this on mobile?

Here is some documentation to get you along:

[Controlling Ratios of Flex Items Along the Main Axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax)